# MYSQL server running query very slow on 1 Million records

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL to manage book library data, here is my main table

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`bookId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`pageNum` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`pageData` longtext
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Now when I run this query

```
SELECT c.id, c.bookId,c.pageNum, c.pageData, o.BookName FROM book c  left 
join kotarbooks o on c.bookId=o.BookId WHERE pageData like '%[Search Word]%'"
```

It takes about 3 minutes

and when I run query

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE bookid=[bookid] AND pageNum=[pageNumber]
```

it takes about 2 minutes
Is there any idea to speed up these queries?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Look up for "indexing". It'll speed up the look ups

Comment: No indexes? No foreign keys? What is `id` and why do you need it as well as `bookId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I run query `SELECT * FROM book WHERE bookid=[bookid] AND pageNum=[pageNumber]`
>   it takes about 2 minutes

You could create index to speed up filtering:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON book(bookid, pageNum);
```

As for `WHERE pageData like '%[Search Word]%'` is not so trivial because you are searching using `'%'` at the beginning and it makes a query not [SARGable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable).

Answer (score 0):

The `LIKE` expression:

```
WHERE book.pageData LIKE '%[Search Word]%'
```

is not sargable, and therefore any index on the `book` table likely would not be used by MySQL.  So, we can instead approach a strategy of a full table scan on the `book` table along with an index on the `kotarbooks` table:

```
CREATE INDEX kotaridx ON kotarabooks (BookId, BookName);
```

The inclusion of the `BookId` column should help the join, and `BookName` covers this column, since it appears the select clause.